# User already authorised login, jquery to Api

Tags: jquery, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

we have an ASP.NET core app, that has an API on another URL to supply its data.

So locally I am running like this:

Api: http://localhost:5001
Web app: http://localhost:5002
Identity server: http://localhost:5000

So our user is logged into the application via the web app (using OpenId), and so has a cookie somewhere that means the user can access the web app form now on.

Great!

So what I want to do is make an ajax call to the web api that will allow them to get some data in the background.

The issue is that I am unsure how to do this jquery.get with authorisation parameters.

I guess I need their access token somehow?

```
jQuery.get("http://localhost:5001/UserProcessData/Id",
                    {
                        query: request.term
                    },
                    function(data) {
                        // assuming data is a JavaScript array such as
                        // ["one@abc.de", "onf@abc.de","ong@abc.de"]
                        // and not a string
                        response(data);
                    });
```

Comment: Yes, you need the access token. How are you authenticating in the Web app. Using the Microsoft Middleware or using some js client?

Comment: We are using Identity Server 4 with OpenID

Comment: Which OpenID library you are using? That was my initial question - is it `oidc-client-js` (authenticating on the client side) or is it the Microsoft Middleware (authenticating on the server side)? Can you add some code? It will be easier to understand